# How to import Image in Python3.5 under windows from PIL/Pillow

Tags: python, image, import, python-imaging-library

I want to write a little app to convert some images. 
I think to have to use `Image.open()`, so I have to import the `Image` module. Right?

If so, here my problem. I have read [other questions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505958/why-cant-python-import-image-from-pil) but any of them worked for me. I tried:

`import Image` => `ImportError: cannot import name 'VERSION'`

`from PIL import Image` => `ImportError: cannot import name 'VERSION'`

`from Pillow import Image` => `ImportError: No module named 'Pillow'`

In [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) I read:

```
Pillow and PIL cannot co-exist in the same environment. Before installing Pillow, please uninstall PIL.

Pillow >= 1.0 no longer supports “import Image”. Please use “from PIL import Image” instead.
```

In my virtual enviroment I had PIL and Pillow directory but `pip list` gave only Pillow (3.1.0) so, even reading [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43560898/import-image-using-pillow-no-module-named-pil), I try to uninstall PIL using pip but it can't find PIL, so I just delete the directory PIL and installed Pillow-PIL (now it appears on `pip list` and there's the directory `Pillow_PIL` on my `venv\Lib\site-packages\`) now:

`import Image` => `ImportError: No module named 'PIL'`

`from PIL import Image` => `ImportError: No module named 'PIL'`

`from Pillow import Image` => `ImportError: No module named 'Pillow'`

`from Pillow-PIL import Image` => `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` (on the minus sign)

`from Pillow_PIL import Image` => `ImportError: No module named 'Pillow_PIL'`

`apt-get install python-imaging` => `"apt-get"` command unknow (my free translation)

So, what now?

Edit: full error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prova.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Image
  File "D:\Python\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\Image.py", line 1, in <mod
ule>
from PIL.Image import *
  File "D:\Python\Envs\possedimenti\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 29, in
 <module>
    from PIL import VERSION, PILLOW_VERSION, _plugins
ImportError: cannot import name 'VERSION'
```

Comment: What OS? Windows? Linux? And what's the full error (Before "cannot import name VERSION")?

Comment: OS is Windows7. Edited topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you install `Pillow`, it installs a module that you import as `PIL`. `Pillow-PIL` is apparantly a "Pillow wrapper for PIL compatibility".

It is generally not a good idea to delete files from `site-packages`, but to use a package installer like pip to do it.

To remedy this, I would suggest uninstalling Pillow-PIL, PIL (if you have it) and Pillow, and then reinstalling just Pillow.

```
pip3 uninstall Pillow-PIL ; pip3 uninstall PIL ; pip3 uninstall Pillow ; pip3 install Pillow
```